# Understand confusingly similar javascript code snippets

Tags: javascript

Here, there are two different code snippets.  I need to know what the output of each is, and why it produces that output.

```js
var output = (function(x){
        delete x;
        return x;
      })(0);
    
      console.log(output);
```

```js
var x = 1;
var output = (function(){
    delete x;
    return x;
  })();

  console.log(output);
```

Comment: Just test it for the output...

Comment: @AndrewL—"*…and why it produces that output.*"

Comment: I know, but for the output he/she could've just tried it @RobG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)output 0 .The delete operator is used to delete properties from an object. Here x is not an object but a local variable. delete operators don't affect local variables.

2)output 1.Here x is not an object, but rather it's the global variable of type number.

Answer (score 0):

The first snippet is a function that uses an argument, (a value that is given to the function when called), and is given the value `0`, while the second snippet uses a global variable that stores the value 1.